# Multi voltage power source and negative dc line

Tags: power-supply, teensy, negative-voltage

I'm working on an audio project with a Teensy board.  The teensy itself is powered by 3.3v, but I want to use balanced audio in/out module that both need a negative voltage rail and a higher voltage altogether.  I relatively new to that universe, so I've powered everything I worked on so far from the MCU board.
So I'm looking for two things:

1. A 3.3v rail
2. +/- 15v rails

Also, on the long run, I'll want the option to have that unit battery powered.

Any read/tutorial/article/precious knowledge you guys can share?

Comment: What balanced audio module are you using?

Comment: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14002. Pro audio usually runs on +/-15-20V and my project is intended for that use.

Comment: Mostly I was looking for the current draw of your module, although it looks like you *can* run it on ±3.3V.  But I can understand why you wouldn't want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to also use battery power in the long-term, you're going to need a solution that accepts only positive high voltage and produces all 3 required rails.

Fortunately, your module accepts up to ±18V rails without running it at absolute maximum ratings, so I would look into a switched capacitor voltage converter that can handle +18V and convert it into -18V.

For the logic rail, you can either look into a buck converter (switching voltage regulator) or a linear 3.3V regulator that accepts up to +18V input.  The downside of a regulator is that to drop 18V to 3.3 is going to make a lot of heat.  The downside of a switching regulator is that the switching can induce some noise in the output lines, and pre-made board units are generally more expensive than regulator ICs.  Both can be overcome.

Why 18V?  Well, you mentioned battery power.  Now, you can generate 15V with 10 AA or AAA batteries, or you can use two 9V batteries in series to get 18V.  The Teensy processor has a max draw of 200mA, and the input module only 8mA, so two 9Vs should give you around 2-3 hours of life (based on 400-600mAh)

You then connect everything in parallel, giving you +18V from the battery/PSU, -18V from the converter, and +3.3V from the regulator (switched or linear).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!  I was expecting a single higher voltage source to produce all the needed rails.  To make the bipolar rails, though, I was expecting to have a main dc input of double the voltage (36v to produce +/-18v).  Do you have any component recommendation when it comes to the buck converter and the voltage converter?

Comment: It's fairly easy to produce low voltages from high voltages internally, and it eliminates the need for complex multi-rail power sources that then have to be isolated from each other, etc.

You could use a digital lab supply that has multiple sets of configurable terminals, but that's not travel-friendly, nor does it solve your battery dilemma.

More good info here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/117152/multiple-voltages-off-a-single-source

Comment: Also, product recommendations are considered off-topic here, so I deliberately avoided naming specific components.  But knowing what they're called and what you need the specs to be should be enough for you to narrow down a distributor product list.

Comment: As I've read somewhere you can give recommendations, but not ask for them...  let me edit my comment ;).  Just kidding, I'll find it myself ;)

Comment: I think that linked post has some recommended ICs.

Comment: Indeed it does :)